# Is burnt milk that sticks to a pan something used in cooking ever? Does it have a name?

Tags: milk

This might be a weird question but I have to ask it anyway. I make my dad boiled milk and I find the burnt milk that sticks to bottom of the pan has got a really great taste.

Does it have a name and what sort of recipes would it be used in?

Comment: Welcome! I've made some slight edits to your question to make it on topic here. We aren't a recipe trading site, so asking for recipes is off topic but the name for this and the typical usage is on topic. How burnt is "burnt"? Can you add an image?

Comment: What kind of milk are you boiling? 2% A&D homogenized, pasteurized cow's milk?

Comment: I think it is very relevant that you [edit] in what color *the burnt milk that sticks to bottom of the pan* has, because that ranges from a paste-like milky substance to almost pure charcoal.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answers (in Indian languages):** Thirattu paal (in Tamil); Doodh peda or Khoya (in Hindi/northern dialects).

If you mean you just boiled and reduced the milk to its minimum volume, that is a common recipe for a "milk sweet" in many parts of India, to my knowledge. In south india, in the state of Tamil Nadu, it is called 'Thirattu paal'. That just loosely translates to 'stirred milk' where paal definitely stands for milk.

In the northern regions of india, it is an intermediary to "doodh peda" where doodh means milk and I dont know what peda means. Maybe it means "soft block".

Here's is one '[recipe](http://www.cookatease.com/thirattu-or-theratti-paal-doodh-peda-paal-khoa)` that calls for a low heat simmer, so things don't burn unless your vessel is thin bottomed. Usually heavy bottom vessels are used for low heat stirred sweet recipes with milk. You can add small amount of sugar, grated vanilla or cardamom powder etc to flavor it additionally.

Comment: 'milk sweet' is roughly the translation of the Mexican 'dulce de leche', (sweet of milk) but most modern (American?) recipes start from sweetened, condensed milk rather than fresh milk.

Comment: It does not look that your answer is related to **burnt** milk.

Comment: It is, all you have to do is forget that you're simmering it and go watch your favorite show on demand. You WILL get  burnt milk. Have lot of experience with this accidental burnt milk recipe.
Seriously though, it depends on the level of "burnt". Burning that occurs while boiling milk at medium heat is fairly similar in consistency to what I was attempting to describe.